# How to check if time is between two times

Tags: formula

I am creating a field to identify if a Resource is scheduled to work based on the current time without considering the date. I'm using the formula `IF(Current_Time__c >= Time_In__c && Current_Time__c <= Time_Out__c, "Online", "Offline")` but it will show Offline especially when a Resource's schedule jumps to the next day (ex: 1:00 AM the next day). Is there a workaround without the need to consider dates?

**Sample Goal**

Current Time: 11:00 PM 
Time In: 9:00 PM 
Time Out: 6:00 AM 
Status: Online

Comment: By definition, a Time field is independent of dates, so you will have to use Date Time for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF(
    Time_In__c <= Time_Out__c, 
    IF(
        Current_Time__c >= Time_In__c && Current_Time__c <= Time_Out__c,
        "Online", 
        "Offline"
    ),
    IF(
        Current_Time__c >= Time_In__c || Current_Time__c <= Time_Out__c,
        "Online", 
        "Offline"
    )
)
```

The formula checks whether the time in is before time out. If it is, then you use your original formula. If not, then the schedule spans two days, so Online is any time after time in (until midnight) or any time before time out (after midnight).

Comment: This is brilliant! Never thought about this. Thank you so much Fred. You're a lifesaver.